# Subtract every 4th column from a defined column

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out a way to subtract every 4th column from a defined column (eg A1-A, A2-A and so on), I want to make this a function that will work with different column names and dataframes of different sizes. Ideally it would run through all four columns (cols A to D). Any tips?

```
A   B   C   D   A1  B1  C1  D1  A2  B2  C2  D2
50  40  60  70  55  45  67  70  50  40  60  75
50  40  60  70  70  60  90  75  50  40  60  70
25  0   50  75  40  0   60  70  50  25  70  80
```

Result that I want is:

```
A1  B1  C1  D1  A2  B2  C2  D2
5   5   7   0   0   0   0   5
20  20  30  5   0   0   0   0
15  0   10  -5  25  25  20  5
```

This function comes close (substracts the 3rd column from the 1st and 2nd, then the 6th from the 4th and 5th, and so on) but I cant figure out how to adjust it to suit my needs:

```
nth <- function(x,n) {
  colsA <- (1:ncol(x))[1:ncol(x)%%n!=0]
  colsB <- rep((1:ncol(x))[1:ncol(x)%%n==0], each=n-1)
  x[,colsA] <- x[,colsA] - x[,colsB]
  x
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `DF` is the input data.frame (as in Note at the end) then:

```
n <- 4
DF[-(1:n)] - as.matrix(DF[1:n])
```

giving:

```
  A1 B1 C1 D1 A2 B2 C2 D2
1  5  5  7  0  0  0  0  5
2 20 20 30  5  0  0  0  0
3 15  0 10 -5 25 25 20  5
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "A   B   C   D   A1  B1  C1  D1  A2  B2  C2  D2
50  40  60  70  55  45  67  70  50  40  60  75
50  40  60  70  70  60  90  75  50  40  60  70
25  0   50  75  40  0   60  70  50  25  70  80
"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

An solution using `apply` can be achieved as:

```
n <- 4
t(apply(df,1,function(x)x[(n+1):length(x)]-rep(x[1:n],(length(x)-n)/n)))
#      A1 B1 C1 D1 A2 B2 C2 D2
# [1,]  5  5  7  0  0  0  0  5
# [2,] 20 20 30  5  0  0  0  0
# [3,] 15  0 10 -5 25 25 20  5
```

Another option can be as:

```
n <- 4
df[-(1:n)] - df[rep(1:n,(ncol(df)-n)/4)]
# A1 B1 C1 D1 A2 B2 C2 D2
# 1  5  5  7  0  0  0  0  5
# 2 20 20 30  5  0  0  0  0
# 3 15  0 10 -5 25 25 20  5
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"A   B   C   D   A1  B1  C1  D1  A2  B2  C2  D2
50  40  60  70  55  45  67  70  50  40  60  75
50  40  60  70  70  60  90  75  50  40  60  70
25  0   50  75  40  0   60  70  50  25  70  80",
header = TRUE)
```